# How to change the version of Newtonsoft.Json used by netstandard 2.0 library

Tags: c#, json, nuget, .net-standard-2.0

I created the netstadard 2.0 class library that references Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.3 nuget. When I build the library and check the referenced assemblies via **Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()** I see that my library references Newtonsoft.Json version 12.0.0 instead of 12.0.3.

Publishing the same library via **dotnet publish** command copies 12.0.3 version of Newtonsoft.Json as well.

However, if I try to load that netstandard library from .net core 3.1 app dynamically using **Assembly.Load()** and then use reflection to access type information I get the exception that Newtonsoft.Json version 12.0.0 could not be loaded.

How can I force my class library to reference the 12.0.3 version instead of 12.0.0 which does not even exist on nuget?

Comment: Use a binding redirect? Binding redirects are generally auto-generated as needed; and if used from a library loaded dynamically it's likely the loader wasn't part of the same build chain (that is, did not directly reference the assembly using Newtonsoft.Json, and thus did not have such an appropriate binding redirect). Either a manual binding redirect or directly including the 12.0.3 version as a dependency of the loader project/build should suffice.

Comment: Is there a way to either remove this seemingly pointless redirection (why would I want the old version anyway?) or somehow pass redirection information to the Assembly.Load() call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Assembly version in *Newtonsoft.Json* returns 12.0.0.0 by design.  Package Versions and Assembly Versions aren't directly tied together and for various reasons can be different.  (I for one sometimes forget to update the assembly version when I increment my package version.)

If you look at the [buildScripts.ps1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/936acbf622b51dcc2fbd214199d22c7a639d3c1b/Build/build.ps1) in the repo you can see where AssemblyVersion is specifically set to the major version plus **0.0** when the AssemblyVersion is empty - which it is, since it isn't set anywhere else in the script.

If multiple packages are referencing different versions of *Newtonsoft.Json*, then just reference the 12.0.3 package directly in your project.  At that point calling `Assembly.Load("Newtonsoft.Json")` should load the version you want.

Comment: Thanks. You are correct, but many people all over the world are probably confused by the fact that 12.0.3 really means 12.0.0.